# how to close an application on clicking the OK button of windows phone 7 application

Tags: c#

I am building an application where i need to have an exit button. Now on the button click event i want to display a messagebox with OK and cancel button and when OK is clicked i want to exit the application and when cancel is clicked i want to stay in the same page. Previously i worked on message box with ok and cancel button like this:

```
private void Donate_Click3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("This Will Take You Out Of The App And Forward You To Our Contribution Website!",
                                              "", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

    if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Donate.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    else
    { }
}
```

Please help to fix the issue

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? You are providing code that you are used to using, but I still don't know what is the issue you are facing? Is it what code to use in the Exit branch? The OK branch?

Comment: @DamianSchenkelman The code that i have provided has an ok and cancel button and when ok is clicked i am directed to a new page and when cancel is clicked i stay in the same page. But now my issue is that when the exit button is clicked i want to display a message asking confirmation from the user whether he is sure to exit the app and when ok will be clicked in this case the application should close and when cancel is clicked it should stay in the same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
{
    while (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
    {
        NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
    }
    NavigationService.GoBack();
}
```

Comment: here it stays in the same page. It doesnot close the app on clicking OK

Comment: updated. the while loop cleans backstack, then call `GoBack()` once again to exit